# Permanently change selected text background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can I permanently change the background color of DIV text when I select it ?
What I am trying to achieve is a highlight effect like this: [image]

Anyone can instruct me how to accomplish this with javascript?

I appreciate your help a lot.

EDIT: I need my text to stay highlighted and highlight multiple texts without losing the highlight of the previous ones.

Comment: add `::selection {color: black; background: yellow;}` in your CSS file - to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks but I need my text to stay highlighted and highlight multiple texts without losing the highlight of the previous ones

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. But please add this information to your question before posting it? you are posting half of the requirement - which does not help anyone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event listener in javascript and when a text is selected at that time need to change the color like below

```
function logSelection(event) {
  // Get Selection
  sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  }
  // Set design mode to on
  document.designMode = "on";
  if (range) {
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
  // Colorize text
  document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "red");
  // Set design mode to off
  document.designMode = "off";
}

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('select', logSelection);
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with p tags or divs instead of inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Use `::selection` selector to override the default color:

```css
::selection{
  background: #FFD24D;
}
```

```html
<p>A team of horses will struggle to chase down a spoken word.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need text to stay highlighted

Comment: I see, you should include that information so that people can help you more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Custom Highlight API, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Custom_Highlight_API, is designed to do exactly what you want. In JS you can mark ranges as having a named highlight style, and in CSS you define what that highlight is. The browser should do something that looks like selection, but is persistent. In your case, you can query the selection range and apply the highlight to that range.

For example:

```
    <style>
        div::highlight(foo) {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="highlighted">This is highlighted text</div>
    <script>
        function markSelection(event) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
                 range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            }
            let h = new Highlight(range);
            CSS.highlights.set('foo', h);
        }

        const input = document.querySelector('input');
        input.addEventListener('select', logSelection);
    </script>
```